# Getting a Docker x509 Certificate Error after upgrade

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, docker-desktop

I recently migrated my dev environment from Windows Home to Pro and as part of the upgrade installed Docker Desktop instead of using Docker Toolbox.

After the upgrade, using the default Docker Desktop instance I kept receiving some variation on the below error.

> Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.abc.xyz.net/v1/users/:
>   x509:  certificate is valid for *.xyz.net, xyg.net, not
>   docker.abc.xyz.net

What could be causing the problem? I have searched around the internet for hours and all the different solutions have no effect. Restarting Docker, uninstall and reinstall.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

It appears as part of the migration from Docker Toolbox to Docker Desktop a number of entries are leftover in the hosts file on Windows that cause a conflict when Docker is trying to access any external network. The simple fix? Remove these 5 lines from my hosts file

```
52.3.153.154    index.docker.io
34.200.28.105   registry.docker.io
52.20.146.203   registry-1.docker.io
54.152.209.167  auth.docker.io
52.222.149.24   dseasb33srnrn.cloudfront.net
```